# Why is the query planner only using one column of two in the index?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.7

I have a table on MySQL 5.7 with the following definition and indexes:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col1                    | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| archive                 | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
...
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name          | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| my_table    |          0 | PRIMARY                            |            1 | id                   | A         |     1086069 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table    |          1 | indx1                              |            1 | archive              | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table    |          1 | indx2                              |            1 | archive              | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table    |          1 | indx2                              |            2 | created_at           | A         |     1086069 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

When I run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table r WHERE r.col1 IN(1,4,6,10) AND (archive = 0) ORDER BY r.created_at DESC LIMIT 0,1001` I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                      | key                                | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | NULL       | ref  | ...                                                                                                                                                | indx2                              | 5       | const | 158522 |    50.96 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

When I run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table r USE INDEX(indx1) WHERE r.col1 IN(1,4,6,10) AND (archive = 0) ORDER BY r.created_at DESC LIMIT 0,1001` I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | NULL       | ref  | ...                     | indx1                   | 5       | const | 158522 |    40.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems that in the first case, when not using the index hint, the query planner is not using `created_at` in the index because of the `DESC` clause, which MySQL 5.7 doesn't support. But why is it that in the extra column I see `Using where` when using `indx2` and `Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort` when using `indx1`? The query also runs twice as fast. Why is that?

*Edit*: Adding `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `archive` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `indx1` (`archive`),
  KEY `indx2` (`archive`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2298216 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Does it run faster with index1 or index2?

Comment: Runs faster with indx2.

Comment: OK. That's what I would expect, too. So what is the question about? You want an explanation about the meaning of `Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort` ?

Comment: Two questions. First, it seems that even when using indx2 the DB uses only the first column, so it's identical to indx1. Yet, it still runs faster. Why is that? Second, the `extra` section is different when using indx1 and indx2, why is that?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but when using indx2, It does use both columns. It's not very clear in the explain but there is no "filesort" which is good (one reason that is faster), it doesn't need to do any sorting. The second column of the index matches the ORDER BY of the query.

Comment: The `key_len` column says 5 in both `EXPLAIN` queries, which means it's only using the first, int(11), column. Also, AFAIK MySQL 5.7 doesn't support descending order indexes.

Comment: @Johnny - In my Answer, I have commented on some of your statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.
- Add `INDEX(archive, col1)`, it *may* help performance.
- key_len=5 for a 4-byte `INT` means that it is NULLable; nothing else.  (`key_len` provides no clue of whether any columns are used for `ORDER BY`.)
- Which rows really need to be `NULLable`?  (Change to `NOT NULL` where appropriate.)
- "when using indx2 the DB uses only the first column" -- Maybe, maybe not.  It does use only the first column for the `WHERE`, but notice that it does not say `filesort`, so it used the second column to avoid the sort.
- If you change the `IN` list, the query may run faster or slower, depending on how fast it finds 1001 relevant rows.
- The "filesort" is fast because it is sorting only 1001 rows, not 158K rows.  And it will probably do it in RAM.  ("FILEsort" is a misnomer.)
- 5.7 does not have `DESC` *indexes*; all BTrees are stored `ASCENDING`.  But it can, in some cases, use the `INDEX` even when you have `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.  (Including all the cases in your Question and my Answer.)

Comment: Thanks, I've added `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. I thought `key_len` indicated the use of the columns in the index overall, not just for filtering, so that's good to know. In which cases is an index usable even with `DESC` in 5.7?

Comment: @Johnny - Alas, `EXPLAIN` has some limitations; that is one.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` is more detailed and provides more information; check it out.

Answer (score -2):

Right now you have no index on col1 even though that's the first item in your where clause.

You should definitely create an index on the aggregate of col1, archive and created_at.

This should solve your speed issue as well.